# Can not debug javascript inside PDF using adobe acrobat 9 pro in IE, Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, pdf, browser, acrobat

I am trying to debug javascript code inside a pdf using Internet Explorer o Firefox but i am not able to see the code to debug. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFuHC.jpg)

Locally I can debug it but I need to do it inside a browser because a java application sends data to the pdf form.

I am using ie 11 and adobe acrobat pro 9. I can see the console but not the javascript console so i can not debug it. Does anyone knows how to configure to see the javascript code in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat/PDF debugging is only possible when the document runs in Acrobat, and it is not possible under the browser.

Comment: They told me that browser pdf can be connected to the local pdf and then debug the local pdf with the browser pdf data. But i dont know how to make this "connection". Any idea ?

Comment: They? could you elaborate? I am not aware of such a connection. What you can do is submits etc. from the form locally opened in Acrobat.

Comment: The guy who was working before of me in my work place told me before leaving that you can do it. He was using win xp and adobe pro 6. Not sure how but i know there is this possibilitty. Thanks anyway. If i find the solution I will post it.